# derivative of this special function

Tags: derivatives

I would like to take the first derivative of the following function respect to `x`. what is the derivative of this function with respect to `x`?

$$f = {(e^{y-z})}^{e^{xw}}$$
where y, z, and w are known.

Comment: Is that power $\exp{(xw)}$?

Comment: @  DavidButlerUofA. Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is the following:
$$
\begin{align}
f &= (e^{y-z})^{e^{wx}}\\
&= e^{(y-z)e^{wx}}\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= e^{(y-z)e^{wx}} \frac{d}{dx}[(y-z)e^{wx}] \quad\text{by the chain rule}\\
&= e^{(y-z)e^{wx}} [(y-z)we^{wx}]\quad\text{because $(y-z)$ is a constant}\\
&= w(y-z)e^{wx}e^{(y-z)e^{wx}}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to write, from $$f = {(e^{y-z})}^{e^{xw}}$$  $$\log(f) = e^{xw} (y-z)$$ and then, by differentiation of both sides, $$\frac{f_x'}{f}=we^{xw} (y-z)$$ and then $f_x'$

Comment: Not $log(y-z)$ but $log(e^{y-z})$

Comment: @DavidButlerUofA. Good catch ! Thanks for pointing it ! I edited. Cheers :)